# How to find the maximum common subtree

Tags: algorithm, hash, tree

there is a tree, and the tree is defined as

```
public class TreeNode 
{
    int val;      
    vector<TreeNode *> children;      
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }      
}
```

please find the maxmum common subtree(have the most number of nodes, the val of each node does not matter, just the structure of the subtrees be the same)

ex,

```
           1                   
      /    |      \                  
     2     3       4                 
    /    / | \   / | \                
   5    6  7  8  9 10 11
```

subtrees with root 3 and 4 are the maxmum common subtree(note,there may be more than two subtrees are the common subtree),

output the roots of the maximum subtrees.

I think the brute force method is not good, what about hashing, but I dont figure out how to hashing the 
structure of a tree.

Comment: One way to represent a rooted (sub)tree is with a string containing opening and closing parentheses.  That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing sounds good. Let's switch to a binary tree representation of general trees, where the left child of the binary tree is the first child of the general tree, and the right child of the binary tree is the next sibling of the general tree. Your tree looks like this now.

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   /   / \
  /   /   \
 /   /     \
5   6       4
     \     /
      7   9
       \   \
        8   10
             \
              11
```

We can encode this tree Lisp-style, using `nil` and `cons`.

```
cons(cons(cons(nil, nil),
          nil),
     cons(cons(nil,
               cons(nil,
                    cons(nil, nil))),
          cons(cons(nil,
                    cons(nil,
                         cons(nil, nil))),
               nil)))
```

Let `H` be the set of hash values. If we specify a hash value `nil : H` and a binary operator `cons : H * H -> H` on hash values, then we get a hash function. Here's one possibility. Let `f` be a [pseudorandom function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) from arbitrary-length strings to fixed-length hash strings.

```
nil = f("")
cons(a, b) = f(a + b)
```